# How can I transfer data between two phones in a local wireless network for testing?

Tags: java, android

For testing purposes, I'm managing to develop a chat app to work through local wireless network. What would be the best options for the communication transfer? (assuming that the only information that each phone have it's the local IP) Sockets?

I referred chat because It's just for testing, my purpose is to transfer data like value of some variables, arrays etc.

Appreciate any idea/suggestion :)

Comment: I am confused by your question, are you asking about file transfer or just simple messaging/chat?

Comment: @Hyangelo you are completely right, I'm talking about transfer of small packets of data (variables, arrays, things like that). No file transfer!

Comment: Filed an edit so the title will say data instead of file transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple Sockets and Buffered streams. Formulate a set of JSON encoded messages that you need. Wrap your data using those messages and send it through the socket. You need to incorporate a way to indicate how long the JSON message is since from experience, there are lag/gaps sometimes that happen in the middle of message transmit/receive. What we did was the first 4 bytes(e.g. an Int) of the message indicates the (byte)length of the succeeding message. E.g. if you have json string 30 bytes long, you send 30(in bytes) first then the actual message such that all transmission over the socket is by pairs of length-payload combinations.

Personally, I've done this in an android project. The advantage of this over going the ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream route is that is definitely lighter and interoperable with other platforms(e.g. iOS, etc). We even did file transfer using chunked base64 encoded json payloads(so all messages are still in JSON).

I am not sure the length-payload pair is the best/only way to go about it though.

Comment: the problem is that with Sockets I'll always need the open port availability problem... am I right? The app is supposed to work in many WLAN, I'm not sure how should I solve this problem...

Comment: Well your server has to be listening to a port so that the clients can connect. If you really need some sort of way to advertise your service(e.g. a server session) you can try looking at ZeroConf particularly at the jmDns library. I've personally used that before to broadcast open sessions.

Answer (score 2):

Probably one of the simplest options would be to just use a Socket, wrap its streams in a `PrintWriter` and a `LineNumberReader` and then send JSON-encoded data. Should be more than adequate for small variables/arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Use an existing chat library (like [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp)) which provides an implementation of a standardized chat protocol ([XMPP](http://xmpp.org/)) and forget about the low level details altogether.

Note: FTP is for file transfers, whatever comms you use it will almost certainly be socket based using TCP.  The only question then is whether you use raw TCP and write the protocol yourself, or use an existing protocol and implementation so you can worry about the application details.

Comment: Yes, I completely forgot FTP is just for file transfer. Unfortunately that chat library does not fit for me, because I'm developing chat just to test the data transfer - I don't really care about chat :) I just need to transfer small packets of data (variables, arrays, things like that)